# Нужна ли запятая при пропуске слова?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после "только"? Я так понимаю, пропущено слово "что" и поэтому запятая напрашивается.

Жаль только слишком много времени потеряется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая ставится. При отсутствии "что" "жаль только" рассматривается как вводное предложение, при наличии "что" - как сказуемое.

Comment: Я сейчас перерыла интернет на предмет бессоюзной связи сложноподчиненных предложений. Ведь здесь "жаль только" - это безличное, и второе тоже. Но второе придаточное, можно подставить союз "что". В таком случае возможна вообще такая связь при помощи запятой? Потому что тире в сложноподчиненных предложениях ставится только если придаточное предшествует главному. Про вводные предложения не знаю. Спасибо.